# Possible to use a custom Angular service before bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-bootstrap

I have a service:

```
angular.module('USC').service('TemplateService', function() {});
```

That I would like to use before I manually bootstrap my Angular project:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['USC']);
```

Is this possible? I know I can call var service = angular.bootstrap().get(); for Angular provided services, but how would I call a custom one before the module was initialized?

Comment: Do you want it to be the same service instance that your app will use once bootstraped orr could it be a different instance ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem it would be ideal to be the same service instance, however if it could only be a different instance that is fine, since technically the app has not bootstrapped yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is OK to have a different instance of the service than the one that will be used by the app itself, you can achieve what you want like this:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'yourApp']).get('SomeService').doStuff();
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/q8sTg/)**.

<sub>As you can see the service is re-instantiated (so counter starts from 0) for use within the Angular app.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, yes to me it makes sense to have it re-instantiated as there is not instance of the app itself yet.

Comment: If you want to use the same instance of your service after the bootstrap you can set as a yourApp.constant('SomeService', SomeService);

Comment: Thanks for this tip! In case anyone else also has a "yourApp" which has dependencies, ie angular.module('yourApp', ['yourApp.services']), and need this technique to load some JSON config file, you can define the other service to inject in a different module all toegether, like angular.module('preboostrappStuff',[]). Thanks @ExpertSystem, your demo was what I needed!